# Simple recursion question

Tags: c, recursion, factorial

This code gives every step-result of computing factorial of given number but I want only the final.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long int factorial(int n) {
  if (n <= 1)
    return(1);
  else
    n = n * factorial(n - 1);
  printf("%d\n", n);
  return(n);
}

main() {
  int n;
  printf("Enter n: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  //function call
  factorial(n);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

How about this ?

```
int final;

final = factorial(n);
printf("%d! = %d\n", n, final);
```

And stop using `printf` in the `factorial` function.

Answer (score 4):

So don't use `printf` inside your recursive function but only print the return value inside `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using `printf();` in the recursive function.

Writing `printf();` inside the recursive function is printing the value everytime. So, just place it outside the function.

Like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

long int factorial(int n) {
    if (n<=1)
        return(1);
    else
        n=n*factorial(n-1);
    return(n);
}

main() {
    int n,f;
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    //function call
    f = factorial(n);
    printf("Factorial of %d is %d\n",n,f);     // See the change here ....
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
long int factorial(int n){
     if(n<=1)
        return 1;
     return n*factorial(n-1);
}
```

Comment: or you can return like this way also return ((n<=1) ? 1 : n*factorial(n-1))

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
long int factorial(int n) {    
    if (n<=1)      
        return(1);  
    else    
        n=n*factorial(n-1);  
    //printf("%d\n",n);    
    return(n);
} 

main(){ 
    int n, result;  
    printf("Enter n: ");  
    scanf("%d",&n);
    //function call  
    result=factorial(n);
    printf("%d\n",result);    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>[This answer was originally edited into the question by the original poster, replacing the incorrect code. The question has been restored and the solution re-posted in this community wiki answer.]</sub>

---

Reworked the code and now it looks like this. Thanks for the suggestions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
long int factorial(int n)
{
    if (n<=1)
        return(1);
    else
        n=n*factorial(n-1);
    return(n);
}
int final(int n)
{
    int result = factorial(n);
    printf("%d! = %d\n", n, result);
    return 0;
}

main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    //function call
    final(n);
    return 0;
}
```